# Calculating if a point is within the overlap of two circles

Tags: probability, circles, area, uniform-distribution

Two circles of equal radius (R) intersect as shown below. Assuming more points are uniformly distributed in an area with dimensions D*D, where D = 4*R. What is the probability that a point will be within the shaded area ?

[image]

How can I go about solving a proof for my answer ?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html This might get you started!

Comment: d and D are not the same, right?

Comment: No they aren't  @alittledon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability of being within the shaded area = (shaded area)/(total area).

Total area = $16R^2$.

Shaded area - bit harder to work out!

Copied from @user3491648's answer:

Let $C$ and $D$ be the intersection points. Let $\theta$ be the angle $CAD$. The area of the diamond $ACBD$ is $\frac{1}{2}R^2\sin \theta + \frac{1}{2}R^2\sin \theta = R^2\sin \theta$. Twice the area of the sector $CAD$ of the circle is $R^2 \theta$. So the area shaded is $R^2(\theta - \sin \theta)$.

So probability required is  $\frac{(\theta - \sin \theta)}{16}$. (credit to @toby's comment).

The additional information we need is that $\cos(\theta)=\frac {d/2} R$.

Comment: $A=\frac{(\theta - \sin \theta)r^2}{2}$ then we know the centers are "d" units apart

Comment: @alittledon I don't think that's right.

Comment: So following @user3491648's method.                                                                             The probability is   (R^2)(θ−sinθ) / 16(R^2).

Answer (score 2):

Let $C$ and $D$ be the intersection points. Let $\theta$ be the angle $CAD$. The area of the diamond $ACBD$ is $\frac{1}{2}R^2\sin \theta + \frac{1}{2}R^2\sin \theta = R^2\sin \theta$. Twice the area of the sector $CAD$ of the circle is $R^2 \theta$. So the area shaded is $R^2(\theta - \sin \theta)$